# WordPress version control with git

Tags: wordpress, git

I'm working on a WordPress project and I want to use git for version control, have my project on my Github. I'm currently working on it just in local.

As that's what version control and repository allow, I want to be able to resume any ongoing work on the project from any computer.
As with any other git version controlled project, I've initialized, staged, committed and pushed my project folder. I took care of configuring the WordPress project with the `wp-config.php` file. All this led to have my project on my Github private repository.

When I try retrieving the project on another computer, I get all those files but the configuration starts over and all previous work regarding theme for example is reset, lost.
It might have something to do with database as I currently do not version controls it. I've read a bit about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45457161/how-to-version-control-with-wordpress) and [here](https://blog.codinghorror.com/get-your-database-under-version-control/).
There must be some information I'm currently not aware of. Any recommendation on the best way to do that, insight or best practice regarding WordPress git versioning in local development is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider following the series of article [Using Git with WordPress](https://www.git-tower.com/blog/git-wordpress-1/) by [Kristian Lumme](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/author/kristian-lumme/).

The problem is WordPress relies heavily on its database.
Which is why [Part 4](https://www.git-tower.com/blog/git-wordpress-4/) is about plugins like [WP Migrate DB Pro](https://deliciousbrains.com/wp-migrate-db-pro/) and [VersionPress](https://versionpress.com/), and how they help manage the database.

> For example, if we add a post (or a page) to our local version of the site, commit, push, and then pull down the code on the production site, the post won't appear there.

So you need both Git and the database to manage a WordPress instance in version control.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. The articles actually seem to address my issue. I will give it a try, thank you